# How make several font style selection (Typeface & SharedPreferences)

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to store font style using sharedpreferences or if there is any other method please support me.

```
 // Load Text Font start

    SharedPreferences myTextFont = this.getSharedPreferences("MyTextFont", MODE_PRIVATE);
    textFont = myTextFont.getInt("font", textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());

    textView3.setTypeface(null,textFont);

    // Load Text Font end

   //textExample.setTypeface(textFont);

    //Font Buttons start

    final Typeface typeface1 = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.teqnikuri);
    type_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            textExample.setTypeface(typeface1);

            SharedPreferences myTextFont = getSharedPreferences("MyTextFont", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myTextFont.edit();
            editor.putInt("font",  textExample.getTypeface().getStyle());
            editor.commit();

        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the purpose of changing font style? Would you tell me a bit about it? You could save font int and get when you want to set a custom font to your textview.

Comment: my application is generally text based, because of this i would like to have option, to change font type by customer.

Comment: You can try saving just id of the font user has set as an int, and get the id for setting it on the textview using `ResourceCompat.getFont(context, intId)`